# Should merged questions be closed as exact duplicate instead of just locking?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools, merged-questions, moderator-faq

Currently when merging questions, the stub is auto-locked.

But merge questions are exact duplicates, they should auto-closed as exact duplicate of target question too.

And may be locking is not needed.

[Return to Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118972/140951)

Comment: I think locking is still needed -- the merged question shouldn't be voted on, for example.

Comment: We don't need locking on normal closed as duplicate questions, right? Why the stub question that don't have any answers on it need locking?

Comment: Because merging is for 100% identical questions. It pretty much only happens when someone posts the same question to, say, SO and Programmers and one of them is migrated to the other site. At that point, the OP should not be getting potentially double upvotes or downvotes on the same question.

Comment: Questions upvotes are now only +5 and downvotes are now free, so that potential up/down votes issue is might be rare case now. If the questions is bad, getting downvotes should be fine, and since locking prevent editing/deleting bad one, so auto-locking may be not very good idea.

Comment: I kind of agree with Dori here, you should NOT be merging questions unless one of them is already closed as a duplicate. Where are you seeing this happen otherwise?

Comment: @Jeff, currently merging can technically be done without closing it, right? for example [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/1484/revisions), you may want to argue that, that because of moderator didn't know to close it first. But it will be great, if system automatically do, 1. close as duplicate, 2. merge (without locking).

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the order is supposed to be:

1. Close as duplicate
2. Merge

If you do that, no locking is required.

If what you're merging isn't a duplicate, why are you merging it? Or to look at it from another direction: **why is it possible to merge open questions**?

Answer (score 3):

As I've just completed this process recently I'm adding a new answer.

If you identify two questions you wish to merge and hit `mod|merge` with the url of the target and press enter, the system now responds with a text-only message:

```
At least one of the questions for the merge must be closed
```

So **closure is now enforced**. If you then close the question and repeat `mod|merge` the following happens:

```
Beginning merge of question.Id = 1636 into question.Id = 1639 

Moved 2 answers to master 
Moved 2 comments to master 
Moved 0 favorite votes to master 
Master now has 7 active answers 
Master now has 8 active comments 

Master now has 0 favorites 
Successful merge
```

and now the posts are merged.

---

For information:

In the revision history, it looks like this:

[image: Post revision history]

I've included only the relevant revisions. They are:

1. Closure.
2. Auto-insert-duplicate-thing.
3. Merge statement.
4. Lock of stub.

I believe the lock is applied automatically to the stub to prevent any further action on the stub.

Note to moderators using this: in my case I had users who had answers on both questions. I don't know yet if they were notified; I left them comments post-merge.