# What is so special about merging duplicates that need locking for the merge source?

Tags: support, merged-questions

In the [improvement about implementation of question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/10/improved-question-merging/) there's no indication why the stub should be locked, since the only difference between a merged question and a duplicate is that answers in one were moved to another question, why is locking needed?

This puts us on situations where we can't delete bad signposts or a off topic question which was the merging target. It's possible that this behavior is altered so that it no longer locks the source?

Comment: For one thing, last time I merged questions, it also moved all the comments. Locking the original might be to keep all the new comments and votes in one place, perhaps?

Comment: @Tink that's worthy of an answer, IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [What is a “merged” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158067/282094) (see the section: "Anything else I should know about merged questions?"), and [duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96469/282094) with guessed answers.

Comment: @Rob "The merge stub question is locked to prevent edits to its content that would make the merge no longer make sense" that was Sonic's interpretation. That wasn't part of the design. From the point of view of everything, merge and duplicate is the same thing... just moving answers from one post to the other.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell considering that comments are second class citizens, I would argue that comments on the question should be deleted anyways.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard this is not a discussion, I want to "[understand] how features work and why they work that way". That's what the support tag is for.

Comment: @Braiam in some cases, sure ;) in this case it was Tim's goodbye/thank-you post and some comments should definitely stay. But my theory is only that, a theory... I don't have an answer for you, just speculation :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yeah, I think I have to ask Jeff what kind of glue he was sniffing (he claim he was) so maybe there isn't a good or any reason for it.

Comment: That linked FAQ originally contained a bullet that no-longer-useful merge stubs should be flagged for deletion, but an SO moderator (Cody Gray) edited that text out, claiming that that was an invalid use for flags. I'd probably ping them asking why they edited that out and why they believed that was the case.

Comment: Also, the whole reason why a stub is left behind is because [in the past, merging would *hard* delete the merge source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51096/377214). A stub is left behind so that there's an unanswered duplicate question so that anonymous users are redirected to the target. I believe the lock is there so that this state doesn't change and it continues to redirect for anonymous users, while registered users can see the exact history of what went on.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog said moderator, [doesn't know why they should be locked at all](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51139675#51139675). BTW, the only reason why they hard delete it, was because Jeff was smelling glue. You can find reasoning on the blog post I linked.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog the reasoning to leaving the stub was explained in the blog post. What is not explained anywhere is why it's locked at all.

Comment: It's likely to prevent people from voting to reopen it, which would destroy the relationship between the two questions and stop anonymous user redirects.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog which would be a explanation, not a very reasonable one. Which is why I'm waiting for an employee to answer this.